# Python - Grayscale very low with a mask

Tags: python, numpy, grayscale

I'm working on pictures that have been converted to grayscale with:

```
Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')
```

I add a mask and I plot my picture with it, but while I expect to get grayscale values between 0 and 255, the values are very low as you can see below. There must be something wrong with the format. What do I have to do to get values between 0 and 255?

```
import numpy as np
import Image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma

mask = plt.imread("mask.png")
test = plt.imread("1.png")

width, high = tab.shape
matrix = np.reshape(tab, (width, high))

# I have to force the dimension...
tab = mask[::, ::, 0]

test = tes[::, ::, 0]   
test_mask = np.ma.array(ma.masked_array(test, tab.max()-tab))
```

And this is the plot:

[image]

Comment: without mask is the same, values are low too

Comment: and my numpy type is dtype=float32

Comment: The conversion to grayscale will convert colors based on their perceived brightness. Only pure white will come out 255; if your image is all shades of blue, the values will all be low as blue is the least bright color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using OpenCV it works...

img = cv2.imread('test.png',0)